# How to run the tomcat 8 as a service

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tomcat8

I have installed the tomcat v8.5.23 as client on my ubuntu14.04 machine.Now I want to run it as a service.Please tell me how to run tomcat8 as service from the tomcat8 client.

Comment: You can find many articles explaining this by doing a simple google search. Here is an example using `upstart`: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score -1):

To run tomcat as a service first create a init file as following steps:
create init script in /etc/init.d/tomcat8 folder as:
To run tomcat as a service first create a init file as following steps:
create init script in /etc/init.d/tomcat8 folder as:

```
#!/bin/bash

   ### BEGIN INIT INFO
   # Provides: tomcat7
   # Required-Start: $network
   # Required-Stop: $network
   # Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
   # Default-Stop: 0 1 6
   # Short-Description: Start/Stop Tomcat server  
   ### END INIT INFO

   PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

   start() {
    sh /var/opt/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh
    }
   stop() {
    sh /var/opt/tomcat8/bin/shutdown.sh
    }
   case $1 in
   start|stop) $1;;
   restart) stop; start;;
    *) echo "Run as $0 "; exit 1;;
   Esac
```

and then save it and give 777 permission to this file. after that you can start the tomcat with start/stop/restart command as:
/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start